# Logic App error - ActionFailed. An action failed. No dependent actions succeeded

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-sentinel

I'm running into this error - ActionFailed. An action failed. No dependent actions succeeded - when trying to run this logic app to add an IP to be blocked.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Error

[image]

[image]

I'm not sure where to start. The input looks ok. Help? Thanks in advance!

p.s. - sorry, it won't allow me to post the pics due to not having enough points.

Tried changing some parts of the body. Not sure what to change really.

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft's documentation on [Submit or Update Indicator API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/defender-endpoint/post-ti-indicator?view=o365-worldwide) the request body should be as follows:

```json
{
    "indicatorValue": "220e7d15b011d7fac48f2bd61114db1022197f7f",
    "indicatorType": "FileSha1",
    "title": "test",
    "application": "demo-test",
    "expirationTime": "2020-12-12T00:00:00Z",
    "action": "AlertAndBlock",
    "severity": "Informational",
    "description": "test",
    "recommendedActions": "nothing",
    "rbacGroupNames": ["group1", "group2"]
}
```

Since the error you get is too generic, it isn't clear enough to know exactly.

You are not passing in recommendedActions and rbacGroupNames, they may not be required but may want to pass the column even if no value is included.

I would also validate calling this API using manual values (even the exact value from their documentation) and if that does work, use process of elimination to figure out which property is giving you the trouble.

i.e. application might not accept a space value or combining the two values for description should be done outside of the HTTP call using compose and then passed as a single value of the output.

Comment: Can you give me tips on how to validate the API or point me to a good site to review? I am very new to all of this. Thanks.

Comment: You can download Postman. It is a tool that will allow you to make HTTP calls to test endpoints.